# getClass().getResource() returns null in deployment

Tags: java, swing, icons, getresource

The following code is running fine when i run the application from netbeans

```
ThumbnailLabel lblImg =new ThumbnailLabel(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(
    getClass().getResource("/jewelleryerpapplication/GUI/resources/NoPicture.png")));
```

Then I clean build the solution as mentioned in different posts for this issue.After that when i double click  App.jar from dist folder then following exception occurs.

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:138)
```

Comment: Make sure the path is correct. And try to remove the `/` from the beginning of the path.

Comment: try passing through the classloader, this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource() and be sure you're with a "consistent" object (e.g. not in the constructor)

Comment: @BigMike  I tried your solution but the result is same.

Comment: post a jar tvf of your jar file please

Comment: Please refer to this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9583367/1057230), I hope that, resources folder is the `Source Folder` in your case. If this is the folder that you had added, then i guess you should be using `getClass().getResource("/NoPicture.png")`

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your deployment JAR actually does contain the images :-)

Comment: Yes it contains images with same path . Iverified the path as well.