# Image Is not Loading From Project ClassPath giving error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!"

Tags: java, image, servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the image from project classpath in Servlet on Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646985/how-to-get-the-image-from-project-classpath-in-servlet-on-netbeans)

I have written following codes in servlet file to read image which is saved in "header" folder of my projects classpath.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/header/header.png"));
```

But it is giving following error..

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
```

Here is my projects directory structure..

[image]

Plz guys help me in solving this error.Thanx in advance.

Comment: where do u have your image, tell the path?

Comment: @sunleo Sir i am using netbeans ide and image is in the "header" folder of "web pages" directory.

Comment: i did but same error Sir

Comment: You may want to have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/174184 and this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582261/adding-background-in-jbutton-netbeans-gui-builder/9583367#9583367

Comment: i changed with " BufferedImage  image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/header/header.png"));" but still same error and i am doing it in servlet page of my project