# How to get the image from project classpath in Servlet on Netbeans

Tags: java, image, servlets

I made a `/header` folder in the web pages directory in Netbeans and added an image named `header.png`. Now I want to access this image file in a servlet using the following code:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(" /header/header.png"));
```

But this is not happening, it gives the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!

Below is my project's directory structure:

[image]

How is this error caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please don't repost the same question over and over: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640602/image-is-not-loading-from-project-classpath-giving-error-java-lang-illegalargum If you think you question can be improved, edit it. Or if you can't seem to find it back, then click on your username link in the top bar, it'll lead you to your user profile where you can find all your previously asked questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Class#getResource()` returns an resource from the class path, not from the public web content.

You need [`ServletContext#getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29), or better, [`getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) instead.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/header/header.png"));
```

*(note that I removed the trailing space from the path as well)*

Note that some users may suggest you to use `ServletContext#getRealPath()`, but you shouldn't use it in this particular case as that may return `null` when the container is configured to expand the deployed WAR into memory instead of local disk file system.

#### See also:

- [What does servletcontext.getRealPath("/") mean and when should I use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160639/what-does-mean-in-the-function-servletcontext-getrealpath/12160863#12160863)