# Not able to access the image file when running jar file outside Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, package, embedded-resource, imageicon

```
lblImage = new javax.swing.JLabel();
lblImage.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("E:..path...png"));
```

I added the file like this. I know it is not accessing the path when running the jar file. Help me how to import a image file to java project in Netbeans.

Comment: You should not do like this. Keep all the images in a resource folder in your project itself and get it by getResource method.

Comment: @vels4j: There is no default resource folder. Do I have to manually make a folder and name it as resource or is there any other way in net beans to create a default resource folder?

Comment: you can create your own /projectname/resource/image.png

Comment: Please have a look at this answer regarding how to [**add images to your NET BEANS project**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9583367/1057230), though after following the steps you have to access your images like this `jLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/images/image.extension")));`

Comment: if i want to load another file say xml file then what should i do ?(ex->new file(/path/sample.xml)); –

Comment: Make separate folders for each category of related files inside your `resources` Folder and access them as required.

Comment: @gagandeep:File f=new File(path/sample.xml);This xml file not accesing when i run the jar file after clean and built the projct.please help

Comment: @user1914867 : Please find attached [**NetBeans Project**](http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/gaganisonline/swing/downloads/SwingSample.zip), that might can help you a bit more.

Comment: @Gandeep:But in the the above project still when i am cleaning and building the dist folder is created.when i tried to run jar file from the dist folder it is not working

Comment: @user1914867 : Please do try the link again, now I had added a working thingy in that, and do have a look for, how to access files inside the code. **Line Numbers 30-31**. In order to access files from **JAR FILE**, you  have to use [**YourClassName.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/files/yourFile.extension")**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 6):

Recommended way is place images inside `resource` folders and use it as below:

```
jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/path/to/image.png")));
```

Read More: [NetBeans Doc](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-image-display.html)

Comment: There is no default resource folder. Do I have to manually make a folder and name it as resource or is there any other way in net beans to create a default resource folder?

Comment: The way NetBeans is suggested is typically you create a separate Java package for the resources and place your image resources under that.

Comment: if i want to load another file say xml file then what should i do ?(ex->new file(/path/sample.xml));

Comment: if you have multiple type of resources, then create separate packages like `image`, `xml`

Comment: :please show me an example like this(File f=new File(path/sample.xml))so that i can access it from the package.

Answer (score 1):

Create the image folder in the src folder, put the images in the folder and give the relative path for creating the image icon object

```
     jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image/img1.jpg")));
```

then rebuild the jar .it will access the images from the jar

Comment: In the same manner any way to work with an xml file.to use an xml file like this->new File(/path/sample.xml)